# Multiply operation between images in EmguCV

Tags: c#, emgucv

I wish know if EmguCV permits a simple and efficient way to do what in MATLAB is done with the following line:

```
C = A .* B
```

(assuming that A, B and C are matrix representing grayscale images with the same dimensions and types).

Assuming that I want to do the same operation above, but using two `Image<Gray, byte>` objects of EmguCV, the question is: **is there a way to multiply point by point two image with the same dimensions?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem. Assuming that we have three grayscale images, defined in this way:

```
//We can use, for example, two files with the same dimensions, e.g. 100x100
Image<Gray, byte> A = new Image<Gray, byte>("imgA_100x100.jpg");
Image<Gray, byte> B = new Image<Gray, byte>("imgB_100x100.jpg");

//The image C will be the result of point-by-point multiplication
//We need to initialize it
Image<Gray, byte> C = new Image<Gray, byte>(A.Width, A.Height);
```

In order to perform the multiplication, you simply need to use the following code:

```
CvInvoke.cvMul(A.Ptr, B.Ptr, C.Ptr, scale);
```

The above line perform the multiplication, point by point, with a scale factor that I called `scale`. Using a pseudocode to explain what the code above implies, we can say that:

```
C[i, j] = A[i, j] * B[i, j] * scale
```